# If statement with dynamically appended divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an API call that is parsing through an array of users while appending some elements of the JSON data to divs with a for loop. My issue is that I have an if statement nested within another API call checking for stream status. If stream is null it should append an img and vice-versa for else.

The problem is that the if statement seems to parse through the array of users, but then appends all the results of the statement to each user row. Im trying to apply the if statement to each user in the array individually, then append the correct img. Im assuming the issue is that each dynamically appended div has the same class that is being targeted by the if statement. Let me know what you guys think.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

    // channel call for info, name, logo
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/' + users[i] + '?callback=?', function(datax) {
      console.log(datax);
      $('#streams-list').append(
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-md-1">' +
        '<img src=' + datax.logo + ' class="stream-icon">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-9 stream-row">' +
        '<li class="list-group-item stream-list">' + datax.name + '</li>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-1">' +
        '<li class="list-group-item status-row"></li>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="list-group-item col-md-1 icon-shell status-symbol" >' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
      );
    });
  }
  var online = [];
  var offline = [];

  for (var x = 0; x < users.length; x++) {
    // stream call for status
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + users[x] + '?callback=?', function(data) {
      var status = data.stream;
      console.log(status);
      if (status == null) {
        $('.status-symbol').append(
          '<img src="icons/ic_highlight_off_black_48dp_2x.png" class="status">'
        )
      } else {
        $('.status-symbol').append(
          '<img src="icons/ic_done_black_48dp_2x.png" class="status">'
        )
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your case you can call second `$.getJSON` inside the 1st `$.getJSON` success handler!

Comment: @A.Akram this will work only if he concatenates the images , using the current append will give the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your code: timing and context for your `$('.status-symbol').append()` calls.

The way your code is written, it won't even work if any of ajax calls in the second loop before the ones in the first loop. `.getJSON` is asynchronous, meaning that the processing time and the order of their execution is variable. You need to process your if/else statement callback only after the `getJSON` call is complete for that user.

```
function logStatus(data, $row) {
  var status = data.stream;
  console.log(status);
  if (status == null) {
    $row.find('.status-symbol').append(
      '<img src="icons/ic_highlight_off_black_48dp_2x.png" class="status">'
    )
  } else {
    $(row).find('.status-symbol').append(
      '<img src="icons/ic_done_black_48dp_2x.png" class="status">'
    )
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  (function(user) { //use a self-invoking function to protect the reference to user
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/' + user + '?callback=?', function(datax) {
      var $row = $(
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-md-1">' +
        '<img src=' + datax.logo + ' class="stream-icon">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-9 stream-row">' +
        '<li class="list-group-item stream-list">' + datax.name + '</li>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-1">' +
        '<li class="list-group-item status-row"></li>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="list-group-item col-md-1 icon-shell status-symbol" >' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
      ).appendTo('#streams-list');
      $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + user + '?callback=?', function(data) {
        logStatus(data,$row);
      });
    });
  })(users[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a data attribute `data-user-id` with the user that will help you append to the correct user, right now `$('.status-symbol')` selector appends to all the prezent status-symbol elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

    // channel call for info, name, logo
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/' + users[i] + '?callback=?', function (datax) {
        console.log(datax);
        $('#streams-list').append(
            '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="col-md-1">' +
            '<img src=' + datax.logo + ' class="stream-icon">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-9 stream-row">' +
            '<li class="list-group-item stream-list">' + datax.name + '</li>' +
            '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-1">' +
                '<li class="list-group-item status-row"></li>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div data-user-id="'+ i +'" class="list-group-item col-md-1 icon-shell status-symbol" >' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        );
    });
}
var online = [];
var offline = [];

for (var x = 0; x < users.length; x++) {
    // stream call for status
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + users[x] + '?callback=?', function (data) {
        var status = data.stream;
         console.log(status);
        if (status==null){
            $('.status-symbol[data-user-id="'+ users[i] +'"]').append(
                '<img src="icons/ic_highlight_off_black_48dp_2x.png" class="status">'
            )
        } else {
            $('.status-symbol[data-user-id="'+ i +'"]').append(
                '<img src="icons/ic_done_black_48dp_2x.png" class="status">'
            )
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But for some reason it keeps appending the data-user-id as undefined, instead of the users. What could be causing this?